# Argument passed to call that takes no arguments on swift for Webview

Tags: swift, xcode

I am building a webview on xcode with swift and the error

> Argument passed to call that takes no arguments on swift for Webview

I am building a webview on xcode with swift and the error Argument passed to call that takes no arguments on swift for Webview

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  GenuineApp
//
//  Created by Kennysoft-Macbook on 11/10/22.
//

import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showWebView = false
    private let urlstring: String = "https://www.genuineict.com"
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 40) {
            WebView(url: URL(string: urlstring)!).frame(height: 500.0)
                .cornerRadius(10)
        }
    }
}
struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var url:URL
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
        return WKWebView()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        UIView.load(request) Here is the error Argument passed to call that takes no arguments on swift for Webview
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

This looks good but it is not working on the latest xcode is there anyone using xcode with swift in 2022
Am building a webview on xcode with swift and the error Argument passed to call that takes no arguments on swift for Webview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UIView.load()` method you are calling doesn't take any arguments, so XCode is correct in their assessment. You can control-click on the `.load` method and go to the documentation to verify this.

What you probably wanted to do is pass the `URLRequest` to the `WKWebView` that you're creating. By making the return value of `makeUIView` specific (so not using `some` to make it opaque), the `updateUIView` method will also recognize it as the incoming `uiView`. You can then call the correct `WKWebView.load(_:)` on it:

```
struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var url: URL
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        WKWebView()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        uiView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it works fine. I'll like you to be my code mentor.